# Why is the passive form "He was determined" used in this sentence?

Tags: passive-voice

I found a sentence in this [link](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in-the-presence-of-somebody):

> He was determined not to complain in the presence of the nurse.

I got confused. 
Was the man controlled by other people? Why the passive form?
Why not:

> He determined not to complain in the presence of the nurse.

Comment: He determined means he figured it was good. He was determined, call it a passive verb, call it an expression, means he was set, settled, focused, or resolute. No one determined him, as he was the agent of determination. Like he *was fixated* on not complaining, or *was mortified* that the nurse might tire of him.

Comment: On a similar note, "He *was closed* to the idea" does not mean someone closed him. The word 'was' does not prove the passive.

Comment: It's not passive, the verb "was" is used to link the subject with its adjective. "Today he is determined" is a complete sentence and means the same as  "Today he is resolute." Note that the adjective, *resolute*, does not end with -d, but some adjectives are past participles e.g. tired, disappointed, excited, etc. Simple Past: "Yesterday he was resolute" = "Yesterday he was determined."